# Get list of all tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I query an Oracle database to display the names of all tables in it?

Comment: Does `SHOW TABLES` (as done in MySQL) work?

Comment: @MartinThoma nope. tried that first, before resorting to Google

Answer (score 1475, accepted):

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables
```

This is assuming that you have access to the `DBA_TABLES` data dictionary view.  If you do not have those privileges but need them, you can request that the DBA explicitly grants you privileges on that table, or, that the DBA grants you the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege or the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role (either of which would allow you to query any data dictionary table).  Of course, you may want to exclude certain schemas like `SYS` and `SYSTEM` which have large numbers of Oracle tables that you probably don't care about.

Alternatively, if you do not have access to `DBA_TABLES`, you can see all the tables that your account has access to through the `ALL_TABLES` view:

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
```

Although, that may be a subset of the tables available in the database (`ALL_TABLES` shows you the information for all the tables that your user has been granted access to).

If you are only concerned with the tables that you own, not those that you have access to, you could use `USER_TABLES`:

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tables
```

Since `USER_TABLES` only has information about the tables that you own, it does not have an `OWNER` column – the owner, by definition, is you.

Oracle also has a number of legacy data dictionary views-- `TAB`, `DICT`, `TABS`, and `CAT` for example-- that could be used.  In general, I would not suggest using these legacy views unless you absolutely need to backport your scripts to Oracle 6.  Oracle has not changed these views in a long time so they often have problems with newer types of objects.  For example, the `TAB` and `CAT` views both show information about tables that are in the user's recycle bin while the `[DBA|ALL|USER]_TABLES` views all filter those out.  `CAT` also shows information about materialized view logs with a `TABLE_TYPE` of "TABLE" which is unlikely to be what you really want.  `DICT` combines tables and synonyms and doesn't tell you who owns the object.

Answer (score 199):

Querying `user_tables` and `dba_tables` didn't work.
This one did:

```
select table_name from all_tables
```

Answer (score 69):

Going one step further, there is another view called cols (all_tab_columns) which can be used to ascertain which tables contain a given column name.

For example:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM cols
WHERE table_name LIKE 'EST%'
AND column_name LIKE '%CALLREF%';
```

to find all tables having a name beginning with EST and columns containing CALLREF anywhere in their names.

This can help when working out what columns you want to join on, for example, depending on your table and column naming conventions.

Comment: I did `select * from cols` and got 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 58):

### For better viewing with `sqlplus`

If you're using `sqlplus` you may want to first set up a few parameters for nicer viewing if your columns are getting mangled (these variables should not persist after you exit your `sqlplus` session ):

```
set colsep '|'
set linesize 167
set pagesize 30
set pagesize 1000
```

### Show All Tables

You can then use something like this to see all table names:

```
SELECT table_name, owner, tablespace_name FROM all_tables;
```

### Show Tables You Own

As @Justin Cave mentions, you can use this to show only tables that you own:

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```

### Don't Forget about Views

Keep in mind that some "tables" may actually be "views" so you can also try running something like:

```
SELECT view_name FROM all_views;
```

### The Results

This should yield something that looks fairly acceptable like:

[image: result]

Answer (score 24):

Simple query to select the tables for the current user:

```
  SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```

Answer (score 22):

```
    select object_name from user_objects where object_type='TABLE';
```

----------------OR------------------

```
    select * from tab;
```

----------------OR------------------

```
    select table_name from user_tables;
```

Answer (score 15):

Try the below data dictionary views.

```
tabs
dba_tables
all_tables
user_tables
```

Answer (score 15):

**Execute the below commands:**

**Show all tables in the Oracle Database**

`sql> SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables;`

**Show tables owned by the current user**

`sql> SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;`

**Show tables that are accessible by the current user**

`sql> SELECT table_name FROM all_tables ORDER BY table_name;`
[image: The following picture illustrates the tables that can be returned from the user_tables, all_tables, and dba_tables views:]

Answer (score 11):

Oracle database to display the names of all tables using below query

```
SELECT owner, table_name FROM dba_tables;

SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables;

SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```

vist more : http://www.plsqlinformation.com/2016/08/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle.html

Answer (score 10):

Try selecting from [user_tables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5443.htm#REFRN26286) which lists the tables owned by the current user.

Answer (score 8):

With any of those, you can select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
    FROM DBA_OBJECTS 
    WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER='SOME_SCHEMA_NAME';

SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
    FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
    WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER='SOME_SCHEMA_NAME';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from dba_tables
```

gives all the tables of all the users only if the user with which you logged in is having the `sysdba` privileges.

Comment: That's actually not correct.  SYSDBA is not required.  You can get access to DBA_TABLES many ways.  1.)  Direct grant on object to user by SYS.  2.)  Grant of SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privilege to user.  3.)  Grant of SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role.

Answer (score 5):

I did not find answer which would point to use

```
DBA_ALL_TABLES (ALL_ALL_TABLES/USER_ALL_TABLES)
```

so decided to add my version as well.
This view actually returns more that DBA_TABLES as it returns object tables as well (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1003.htm).

Answer (score 5):

A new feature available in [**SQLcl**](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)( which is a free command line interface for Oracle Database)  is

**`Tables`** alias.

Here are few examples showing the usage and additional aspects of the feature. First, connect to a `sql` command line (`sql.exe` in windows) session. It is recommended to enter this sqlcl specific command before running any other commands or queries which display data.

```
SQL> set sqlformat ansiconsole     -- resizes the columns to the width of the 
                                   -- data to save space
```

**`SQL> tables`**

```
TABLES
-----------
REGIONS
LOCATIONS
DEPARTMENTS
JOBS
EMPLOYEES
JOB_HISTORY
..
```

To know what the `tables` alias is referring to, you may simply use `alias list <alias>`

```
SQL> alias list tables
tables - tables <schema> - show tables from schema
--------------------------------------------------

 select table_name "TABLES" from user_tables
```

You don't have to define this alias as it comes by default under SQLcl. If you want to list tables from a specific schema, using a new user-defined alias and passing schema name as a bind argument  with only a set of columns being displayed, you may do so using

**`SQL> alias tables_schema = select owner, table_name, last_analyzed from all_tables where owner = :ownr;`**

Thereafter you may simply pass schema name as an argument

**`SQL> tables_schema HR`**

```
OWNER   TABLE_NAME               LAST_ANALYZED
HR      DUMMY1                   18-10-18
HR      YOURTAB2                 16-11-18
HR      YOURTABLE                01-12-18
HR      ID_TABLE                 05-12-18
HR      REGIONS                  26-05-18
HR      LOCATIONS                26-05-18
HR      DEPARTMENTS              26-05-18
HR      JOBS                     26-05-18
HR      EMPLOYEES                12-10-18
..
..
```

A more sophisticated pre-defined alias is known as **`Tables2`**, which displays several other columns.

```
SQL> tables2

Tables
======
TABLE_NAME                 NUM_ROWS   BLOCKS   UNFORMATTED_SIZE COMPRESSION     INDEX_COUNT   CONSTRAINT_COUNT   PART_COUNT LAST_ANALYZED
AN_IP_TABLE                       0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
PARTTABLE                         0        0                  0                           1                  0            1 > Month
TST2                              0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
TST3                              0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
MANAGE_EMPLYEE                    0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
PRODUCT                           0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
ALL_TAB_X78EHRYFK                 0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
TBW                               0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
DEPT                              0        0                  0 Disabled                  0                  0            0 > Month
```

To know what query it runs in the background, enter

```
alias list tables2
```

This will show you a slightly more complex query along with predefined `column` definitions commonly used in SQL*Plus.

*Jeff Smith* explains more about aliases [**here**](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/11/object-search-in-sqlcl/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Oracle Data Dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c05dicti.htm) to get information about oracle objects.

You can get list of tables in different ways:

```
select * 
from dba_tables
```

or for example:

```
select * 
from dba_objects 
where object_type = 'TABLE'
```

Then you can get table columns using table name:

```
select * 
from dba_tab_columns
```

Then you can get list of dependencies (triggers, views and etc.):

```
select * 
from dba_dependencies
where referenced_type='TABLE' and referenced_name=:t_name
```

Then you can get text source of this objects:

```
select * from dba_source
```

And you can use `USER` or `ALL` views instead of `DBA` if you want.

Answer (score 4):

We can get all tables including column details from below query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns;
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is a commented snippet of SQL queries describing how options you can make use of:

```
-- need to have select catalog role
SELECT * FROM dba_tables;

-- to see tables of your schema
SELECT * FROM user_tables;

-- tables inside your schema and tables of other schema which you possess select grants on
SELECT * FROM all_tables;
```

Answer (score 3):

Including views:

```
SELECT owner, table_name as table_view
  FROM dba_tables
UNION ALL
SELECT owner, view_name as table_view
  FROM DBA_VIEWS
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query only list the required data, whereas the other answers gave me the extra data which only confused me.

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to get a list of all columns names belonging to a table of a schema sorted by the order of column id.

Here's the query I am using: -

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE OWNER = 'schema_owner_username' AND TABLE_NAME='table_name'
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is possible to have the list of tables via SQL queries.it is possible to do that also via tools that allow the generation of data dictionaries, such as [ERWIN](https://erwin.com/products/erwin-data-modeler/), [Toad Data Modeler](https://www.quest.com/fr-fr/products/toad-data-modeler/#) or [ERBuilder](https://soft-builder.com/en/erbuilder-data-modeler/). With these tools, in addition to table names, you will have fields, their types, objects like(triggers, sequences, domain, views...)

Below steps to follow to generate your tables definition:

1. You have to reverse engineer your database

   - In Toad data modeler:  Menu -> File -> reverse engineer -> reverse engineering wizard
   - In ERBuilder data modeler: Menu -> File -> reverse engineer

Your database will be displayed in the software as an Entity Relationship diagram.

2. Generate your data dictionary that will contain your Tables definition

   - In Toad data modeler: Menu -> Model -> Generate report -> Run
   - In ERBuilder data modeler: Menu -> Tool -> generate model documentation

Answer (score 0):

To get all the table names, we can use:

```
Select  owner, table_name  from all_tables;
```

if you have dba permission, you can use:

```
Select owner, table_name from dba_tables;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from all_all_tables
```

this additional 'all' at the beginning gives extra 3 columns which are:

```
OBJECT_ID_TYPE
TABLE_TYPE_OWNER
TABLE_TYPE
```

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551167/1227152), no?

Answer (score -1):

I use the ALL_TAB_COLS.  ALL_TAB_COLS describes the columns of the tables, views, and clusters accessible to the current user.

[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_TAB_COLS.html#GUID-85036F42-140A-406B-BE11-0AC49A00DBA3)

```
SELECT
OWNER,
TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME,
DATA_TYPE,
DATA_TYPE_MOD,
DATA_TYPE_OWNER,
DATA_LENGTH,
DATA_PRECISION,
DATA_SCALE,
NULLABLE,
COLUMN_ID,
DEFAULT_LENGTH,
DATA_DEFAULT,
NUM_DISTINCT,
DENSITY,
NUM_NULLS,
NUM_BUCKETS,
LAST_ANALYZED,
SAMPLE_SIZE,
CHARACTER_SET_NAME,
CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH,
GLOBAL_STATS,
USER_STATS,
AVG_COL_LEN,
CHAR_LENGTH,
CHAR_USED,
V80_FMT_IMAGE,
DATA_UPGRADED,
HIDDEN_COLUMN,
VIRTUAL_COLUMN,
SEGMENT_COLUMN_ID,
INTERNAL_COLUMN_ID,
HISTOGRAM,
QUALIFIED_COL_NAME

FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
/*  WHERE add filters here */
```

Answer (score -2):

Tables in the current user - logon schema

```
select * from tabs;
```