# How to distinguish if a database object (in Oracle) is a table or view

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to distinguish between a view and table. Basically, I want to find all the tables which has a particular column name.

```
select table_name from user_tab_columns x where column_name='STUDENTID';
```

The above query also returns views which have the same column. I tried using the following, however, I feel it take long time to run and return...

```
select table_name from user_tables where table_name in (select x.table_name from user_tab_columns x where x.column_name='PLAN_NAME');
```

any suggestions please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: get list of all tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/oracle-get-list-of-all-tables)

Comment: How long is a "long time" to return? I'm kind of skeptical that you've got so many columns and tables that this is taking more than a second.

Comment: The query took 2secs to return, when ran first time on my database. Surprisingly, if I run it run, it takes 0.06 secs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess a join will be quicker than a subselect. Try this:

```
select c.table_name 
from user_tab_columns c, user_tables t
where c.table_name = t.table_name
and c.column_name='STUDENTID';
```

Comment: +1  And, of course, we can use USER_VIEWS to filter out tables in the same way.