# SSIS breaks Oracle Privileges

Tags: oracle, ssis, privileges

I make a privileges to user on one schema at Oracle, when accessing oracle database using SSIS I saw all tables and schema. When I use SQL Plus show me only one schema.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

What query are you running to see tables in SQL*Plus?  If you are querying `USER_TABLES`, you will only see the tables that the current user owns.  If you are querying `ALL_TABLES`, you will see all the tables that you have permission to query regardless of the owner.  If you are querying `DBA_TABLES`, you will see all the tables in the database (though you need additional privileges to query the `DBA%` objects.

There is another question on [how to get a list of all the tables in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/oracle-get-list-of-all-tables/205746#205746) that goes into more detail about this.

Comment: I am using USER_TABLES, Sorry I do not understand the last question, any way when I access to oracle database using "Oracle Provider OLEDB" in SSIS I saw everything tables,viewa and all schema in database

Comment: @HossamAhmed - If you query `USER_TABLES`, you will only see the tables that the current user owns.  If you want to see objects other than tables, you'd need to query other data dictionary views-- `USER_VIEWS` shows you views that the current user owns, for example.  If you want to see objects that you have access to but do not own, you'd need to query `ALL_TABLES`, `ALL_VIEWS`, etc.  That's what most GUI tools query.