# Getting all tables from an oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to retrieve a list of tables from an Oracle connection. I'm not very familiar with Oracle terminology and thus, having hard time finding the information I need.

Right now I can use Microsoft Access to connect via ODBC and it pops up with a "Link Tables" dialog that lists all tables, not just the ones I "own". None of the queries I've tried so far, give me this data.

I'm trying "`SELECT * FROM all_tables`" but that doesn't show me the right data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: get list of all tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/oracle-get-list-of-all-tables)

Comment: Please explain *"doesn't show me the right data*". What do you see? What do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALL_TABLES` will show you all the tables that you have access to `SELECT` from.  `DBA_TABLES` will show you all the tables that exist in the database though you'll need an additional privilege grant to be able to query the `DBA*` data dictionary objects.

Comment: It turns out some of the tables I was seeing were actually views and synonyms. The query `SELECT * FROM ALL_CATALOG` worked for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try `select * from all_tables`, that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It can be.. (If user has dba role)

```
select * from dba_tables
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES
```

It will return list of tables owned by your user.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT * FROM TAB;**    that will show you all the table and views