# Can a single sqoop job be used for multiple tables and be running at the same time

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, data-ingestion

I just started with Sqoop Hands-on. I have a question, lets say I have 300 tables in a database and I want to perform an incremental load on those tables. I understand I can do incremental imports with either append mode or last modified.

But do I have to create 300 jobs, if the only thing in job which varies is Table name , CDC column and the last value/updated value?

Has anyone tried using the same job and passing this above things as parameter which can be read from a text file in a loop and execute the same job for all the tables in parallel.

What is the industry standard and recommendations ?

Also, is there a way to truncate and re-load the hadoop tables which is very small instead of performing CDC and merging the tables later?

Answer (score 0):

There is import-all-tables  "Import tables from a database to HDFS"
However it will not provide way to change CDC column for each table.
Also see [sqoop import multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194232/sqoop-import-multiple-tables/17199029)

There is no truncation but same can be achieved through following.
--delete-target-dir  "Delete the import target directory if it exists"