# JavaDB - CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS - how to?

Tags: sql, create-table, javadb

I'm trying to create table using JavaDB (Derby), but if I try to add IF NOT EXISTS:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS etc (ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(150))
```

I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "NOT" at
>   line 1, column 17.

As I remember it works on MySQL. What is the syntax/simplest method to check if table exists?

**EDIT:**

Finally I found the solution:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "ETC", null);
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Table " +  rs.getString(3) + " exists");
}
```

I noticed that table name is case sensitive if it is created with using quotes "etc", and if not - the name must be upper case. According API documentation: "must match the table name as it is stored in the database".

Answer (score -3):

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='etc' and xtype='U')
create table etc(
   ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(150)
);
```

It will create a table called etc if it doesn't exist.

More of this over [here](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/how-to-create-table-in-mssql-only-if-it-does-not-exist/).

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such sysobjects table in my database. Table list: SYSCONGLOMERATES
SYSTABLES
SYSCOLUMNS
SYSSCHEMAS
SYSCONSTRAINTS
SYSKEYS
SYSDEPENDS
SYSALIASES
SYSVIEWS
SYSCHECKS
SYSFOREIGNKEYS
SYSSTATEMENTS
SYSFILES
SYSTRIGGERS
SYSSTATISTICS
SYSDUMMY1
SYSTABLEPERMS
SYSCOLPERMS
SYSROUTINEPERMS
SYSROLES
SYSSEQUENCES
SYSPERMS. Still get the erorr..

Comment: Try this link; there are more useful things that you can try replacing the first select statement.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle

Comment: None of above methods worked for me.. Maybe for other databases, but not for javaDB/Derby.