# What is the query to display all database in oracle server 9i?

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I like to know the query to get all database in oracle server 9i. Actually my requirement is to select all database in oracle and next to get all table , views , procedures , function in each database. Is their any way to get all these information? I am using oracle spl plus developer.

Comment: You really want to get all database names or all users in a database?

Comment: Do you mean all schemas, rather than all databases? Have you looked at the `ALL_*` and `DBA_*` data [dictionary views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/toc.htm) to get the information? [Here's a starter for tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/205736/266304). (Also SQL*Plus and SQL Developer are different thing, though it shouldn't really matter which you're using).

Comment: i want all database name. Then i need all tables, views, procedures in each database

Comment: An Oracle instance only has one database. The database may contain multiple schemas (aka users), some of which will be system users.

Comment: @DavidAldridge You should add "usually" or "in most cases" to your statement because technically it is possible for a database to be mounted by multiple instances simultaneously.

Comment: Sure, in a RAC system, but what I said was the other way round -- that an instance cannot mount multiple databases. Now that might be changing logically in 12c, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The database names you can get from server file system or check running Oracle Processes.

Then check `select * from DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE','VIEW','FUNCTION','PACKAGE','PROCEDURE')`

Comment: Not true. There is also v$database view.

Comment: Actually i need to list all database names first. Based on the database i need table, view, functions and all.. Actually i am writing a c# code to display all database in oracle. Based on selection of database from that list i need to display table, view , functions and all..

Comment: v$database shows the current database where you are connected on. But it does not show any other DB hosted by the same server - at least not in any case.