# Oracle SQL - Keeping Comments from previous table in new table

Tags: sql, oracle

EDIT:Thank you, I got one step further, but can't seem to get it working since the original tables are accessed by a database link.

I access have a lot of tables with descriptions of the columns in the comments section.

Is there any way to copy the comments over when I create a new table, besides adding it manually afterwards?

```
Select a.tot_sum
      ,b.id
      ,b.size
from original_table a
    ,someother_table b 
where a.id=b.id 
and   b.region in 'North'
```

I can do it manually with some copypasting in excel:

```
Comment On Column Mytable.Tot_Sum
Is 'Total sum of sales';
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
Comment On Column Mytable.Tot_Sum
IS (select comment from column original_table.tot_sum);
```

Or is there a syntax to simply keep the comments when creating a new table?

Answer (score 0):

You can query ALL_COL_COMMNENTS.

You can automate this with a small PL/SQL anonymous block :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_ViewName VARCHAR2(30) := 'XXX';
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR v_Comment IN
  5    (SELECT acc.COLUMN_NAME,
  6      REPLACE(REPLACE(acc.COMMENTS, chr(13), ''), chr(10), '') comments
  7    FROM ALL_COL_COMMENTS ACC
  8    WHERE ACC.OWNER    = 'SCOTT'
  9    AND ACC.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
 10    )
 11    LOOP
 12      dbms_output.put_line(v_comment.column_name || ' - '||v_comment.comments);
 13    END LOOP;
 14  END;
 15  /
EMPNO -
ENAME -
JOB -
MGR -
HIREDATE -
SAL -
COMM -
DEPTNO -

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you have any table with some comments, just replace the USER and TABLE_NAME in my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
comment_ varchar2(255);
begin
  select comments into comment_ from user_col_comments
  where table_name=upper('original_table')
  and column_name=upper('my_column');

  execute immediate 'comment on column new_table.my_column is '''||comment_||'''';
end;
```

`COMMENT` function accept only text literals, that's why I used dynamic query instead of `IS SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

There are DBA-Views for the comments.

DBA_COL_COMMENTS
ALL_COL_COMMENTS
USER_COL_COMMENTS

You could do something like that:

```
declare
  v_comment varchar2(100);
  v_stmt varchar2(4000);
begin

  select comments 
  into v_comment
  from user_col_comments 
  where table_name= 'ORIGINAL_TABLE'
  and column_name='TOT_SUM';

  v_stmt:='comment on column MYTABLE.TOT_SUM IS '''||v_comment||'''';

  execute  immediate v_stmt;
end;
```

Edit: When you have a lot of columns, you could automate it by doing this:

```
declare
  v_comment varchar2(100);
  v_stmt varchar2(4000);
  v_orig_table varchar2(100) :='ORIGINAL_TABLE';
  v_new_table varchar2(100) :='MYTABLE';
begin
  for c in (select column_name
              from user_tab_columns c
             where table_name=v_orig_table
               and exists(select 1 
                            from user_tab_columns
                            where table_name=v_new_table
                              and column_name=c.column_name)) loop
    select comments 
    into v_comment
    from user_col_comments 
    where table_name= v_orig_table
    and column_name=c.column_name;

    v_stmt:='comment on column '||v_new_table||'.'||c.column_name||' IS '''||v_comment||'''';

    execute  immediate v_stmt;
  end loop;

end;
```

Edit 2: Version with SCHEMA_Name and DB-Link

```
declare
  v_comment varchar2(100);
  v_stmt varchar2(4000);
  v_orig_table varchar2(100) :='ORIGINAL_TABLE';
  v_orig_schema varchar2(100) := 'ORIG_OWNER';
  v_new_table varchar2(100) :='MYTABLE';
begin
  for c in (select column_name
              from all_tab_columns@db.link c
             where table_name=v_orig_table
               and owner=v_orig_schema
               and exists(select 1 
                            from user_tab_columns
                            where table_name=v_new_table
                              and column_name=c.column_name)) loop
    select comments 
    into v_comment
    from all_col_comments@db.link
    where table_name= v_orig_table
    and column_name=c.column_name
    and owner=v_orig_schema;

    v_stmt:='comment on column '||v_new_table||'.'||c.column_name||' IS '''||v_comment||'''';
    execute  immediate v_stmt;
  end loop;    
end;
```

Comment: I can almost get this working, but it seems my database link is causing problems. In stead of 'ORIGINAL_TABLE' my statement says 'schema_name.original_table@dblin.something'

Comment: you have to add the db-link to user_col_comments. Don't write the SCHEMA_NAME into my variables, just the table_name  and you have to write it in capital letters

Comment: Thank you! another step closer, but I still cant get it working. I get the error "no data found" on line 16. However, If I change ORIG_OWNER to ORIG_OWNER. (punctuation added) the loop runs, but nothing is added to the columns.

Comment: ORIG_OWNER is the schema_name, just try to get the select-Statement running without PL/SQL for debugging.

Comment: Cant get the block    select comments 
    into v_comment
    from user_col_comments 
    where table_name= v_orig_table
    and column_name=c.column_name; to run. Seems I only find my own columns and comments, not the ones behind the db-link

Comment: I can get this to run on my own database connection, but not on the other connections, not even when I run the same SQL when connected directly to the database and not through a database link: Select * From User_Col_Comments

Comment: Sorry, you should have used all_col_comments, I updated that in my answer.

Comment: here is a little explanations about the difference of user_, all_ and dba_-Views(knowing that stuff makes working with oracle much easier):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle