# Query for all tables and columns in a database in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle

How would you query an oracle sql database for all tables in the database  and the columns associated with them in with single line/statement of code?

Format:

```
Table1
  colums
Table2
  Colums
```

Comment: I believe this answer extensively explains how to do this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle

Comment: Use the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List table and columns in one statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282063/list-table-and-columns-in-one-statement)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from all_tab_columns
```

In this query you see all columns in your table