# List table and columns in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle

How would you in oracle SQL print the name of each table and the columns within that table- by printing the table name once followed by each column within that table on a separate line.

Format should be something like this:

```
Table1
  columns
Table2
  Columns
```

Comment: Do you want a SQL only solution or will a PL/SQL block work for you?

Comment: PL/SQL block is alright as well.

Comment: Have a look at the `USER_OBJECTS` system table (or view), which contains the names and types of all user object, including tables and columns. I think there are separate tables like `USER_COLS` for columns, which should contain the name of the table they belong to. Once you found those tables, it's a matter of joining and sorting.

Comment: If you're using SQL*Plus a simple `DESCRIBE <<table_name>>` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
    DECLARE 
TNAME user_tables.table_name%TYPE;
CNAME user_tab_columns.column_name%TYPE;
CURSOR ct1
IS SELECT table_name from user_tables;
CURSOR ct2 IS SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name =TNAME;
BEGIN
OPEN ct1;
LOOP
FETCH ct1 INTO TNAME;
EXIT WHEN ct1%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TABLENAME:-->'|| TRIM(TNAME));
      OPEN ct2;
      LOOP
      FETCH ct2 INTO CNAME;
      EXIT WHEN ct2%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('             '|| TRIM(CNAME));
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE CT2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE ct1;
END;
```

Comment: Not bad.  I ran this against the example SCOTT schema.  It would not hurt to have some explanation.

Comment: @Patrick - There are two cursors that go in a loop. The first cursor reads all the table names. The second cursor accepts a parameter that is the table name and queries the user_tab_columns view.