# Database oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can i know the list of tables created in each DB using Oracle ? I want to delete the unnecessary ones.

Comment: `tables created with their names` Could you clarify this part?

Comment: Ask it nicely. `Show tables` perhaps...

Comment: Can you re frame the question so that it can be understood better.?

Answer (score 0):

This question/answer should give you the details you need:
[Get list of all tables in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle)

but in summary...

```
-- If you have access
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables

-- Will show what your user has access to
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLES  IN `db`;
```

Where db is the name of your database.