# SELECT a table from oracle data dictionary

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to SQL and recently installed Oracle 11g. I read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle) on selecting all tables from `user_tables`. I'm trying to select a specific table and following some of the suggestions in the post does not appear to work.

The following executes fine and returns all tables available to me including a table named `faculty_t`:

```
select * from user_tables;
select * from dba_tables;
select * from all_tables;
desc faculty_t;
```

But I get error when I do the following:

```
select * from user_tables where table_name = FACULTY_T;
```

The first set of statements confirm that I do have a table named `faculty_t`. However, trying to select this table from `user_tables`, `all_tables`, or `dba_tables` does not appear to work for me right now. The error message reads something like:

```
ORA-00904: "FACULTY_T": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 208 Column: 8
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: maybe because SQL is case sensitive?? try faculty_t not FACULTY_T

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. As you can see from the error message itself, oracle seems to read it as FACULTY_T anyway.

Comment: does the first statement work with you? "select faculty_t from user_tables;"

Comment: Please read the chapter [Basic Elements of Oracle SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)

Answer (score 3):

String literals in SQL are wrapped in `'`.  So:

```
select * from user_tables where table_name = 'FACULTY_T';
```

When you did a `desc faculty_t`, the SQL engine knew that a table name was expected at that spot (the syntax expects a table name there).  But in your select query, sql is just looking for the value of a column that happens to have a string data type, so you need to use the `'` for a string literal.

Comment: Table names are stored in upper case in Oracle.

Comment: I missed that subtle difference. It works with upper case FACULTY_T enclosed in quotes!