# See all tables I have read access to in SQL Developer in fixed window (not script output)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was recently moved from InfoMaker to SQL Developer.   I am trying to create the same view of tables that I had in InfoMaker.   That is,  I have read access to tables owned by multiple other users, and I would like to display them all in one convenient window that is not a script output window.   When answering the question, please note the following:

1. I can see my own tables fine.
2. I can display the tables of one other owner at a time.
3. I can query the table names and they will show up in a scrolling output window.

A good answer to the question would display all the tables I have access to, even from multiple owners, in a single window that is fixed and not connected in any way to scripts or anything else.  It just sits on the screen off to one side, like I printed them out and taped up the piece of paper (which I will do if the InfoMaker style view is not possible).

Thanks very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of all tables in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle)

Comment: This is not the same question.   I am trying to recreate the view I had in InfoMaker, which shows all the tables I have read access to in a window that is not part of the script output AND shows tables from more than one other user, and sits neatly off to the side.   What you posted I already indicated that I know how to do in my question.   Thanks anyway for the link.

Comment: Please note that I tried to comment on the other question, but I do not have enough reputation to do so, so I started a new one.

Comment: I edited your tags.  Your question really just pertains to Oracle's SQL Developer - not SQL at all.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is not a general purpose GUI design tool. If you really need a custom view, you can write your own plugin - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/extensions-083825.html#create

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the possible answers I was anticipating.   I have no control over what software I can get at work at this time, I'm just a lowly office nerd.  Our IT dept is cutting support for InfoMaker and this is what I have to work with at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Write a report.

This report can even have your objects shown as object navigators.

Reports offer filtering, sorting, and search - so you can easily find stuff, vs just scanning the list of objects.

View > Reports.

User Defined Reports > Create a new report.

Supply SQL.

To make the objects 'navigable', follow the instructions [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/sql-developer-query-grid-tricks/)

[image: query returning list of objects you can open by clicking on their name]

Comment: oh, and you can dock your report to a separate doc tab group so you can see it at all times, even if you are working in a SQL Worksheet or in a procedure editor, or even another report...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help.   I was finally able to track down someone who knows the software pretty well, and he told me that the type of view and functionality I had in InfoMaker cannot be reproduced in SqlDeveloper.  That is an acceptable answer.

I'll give that report a try, thanks Jeff Smith