# How get Tables from current Session/User

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm struggling to get tables of given username or current session/user;
I'm able to get all tables by using `select table_name from all_tables;` but it also retrieve default created tables. I just want tables that we created.

Even when I retrieve tables from Pluggable database it also fetch all tables(default-tables-with-$-sign-name) but when I connect pluggable-user in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER then it just show (user-created)tables without default tables.

I want all queries that show tables,users without default($ sign name) table,users; for sqlplus. I'm using ORACLE-12C.

Comment: just use select * from user_tables;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of all tables in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle)

Comment: @FlorinGhita I know, but this also retrieve such stupid tables that I not created. may be that could be default-tables.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I already created a user for given PDBORLC pluggable database and used there this command that still give me extra tables in sqlplus. but in ORACLE DEVELOPER just 4 tables, emp,dept, and 2 others.

Comment: @FlorinGhita should I create Local user or common user? mean username with c##? or just simple?

Comment: did you run **`select * from user_tables`**

Comment: @FlorinGhita yes I run that query, But I'm still getting some tables that I not created. Even for SYSTEM user(in CONTAINER) or scott user in PDBORCL.

Comment: system is not an user created by you. you should connect with a regular user, like scott(predefined) or another created by you.

Comment: Got it Man..!! but what query for users? mean how I get all users that created by my-user? and same from pluggable database that created given user?

Comment: that's another question. You can search on google. For example, I found this: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/List_of_default_database_users

Comment: Please DO NOT use SYS or SYSTEM for your applications/tests/work.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter on the owner:

```
select table_name from all_tables where owner='YOUR OWNER NAME';
```

Comment: show `no row selected` error. even I created one table;

Comment: what user do you use? `select user from dual;` to find it.

Comment: I got SYSTEM. but it also retrieve tables that I not created. ( with some $ sign name ) even for SYSTEM user and SCOTT user for PDBORCL(Pluggable_databse);

Answer (score 1):

You could query the view **[DBA|ALL|USER]_TABLES** depending on the privilege you have.

Querying **USER_TABLES** would provide all the tables owned by the **current owner** you have logged into.

For example,

```
SQL> show user
USER is "LALIT"
SQL> SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;

TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

no rows selected

SQL> create table t(a number);

Table created.

SQL> SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;

TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T
```

While using **DBA/ALL** you must filter the **OWNER** in **UPPER CASE**.

For example,

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE OWNER='LALIT';

TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T
```

Comment: Why no simply use `user_tables` instead? Regular users won't have access to `dba_tables` anyway

Comment: hmm...Updated...Hope now it makes more sense.