# Fetching Usermade Table names from Oracle in java

Tags: java, oracle11g

How to filter out the tables create by programmer from oracle's predfined tables and also want to print those user defined table names also...
Please Help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of all tables in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's tables are owned by predefined schema's, such as SYSTEM, SYS, etc.

You really should be creating tables in your own (set of) application schema. So when you are connected to your schema, the tables are in USER_TABLES.