# Clear a big number of tables with template names fast and easy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have about 30 tables in Oracle. Names of the tables have some **template format**, for example:

> DF_D_AUTO, DF_D_PERSON

and so on. So the first part of a table name is always

> DF_D_

I would like to **clear all these tables**. Of course I can clear them manually one by one.

However I would like to know may be someone knows a good fast way using SQL to clear all such tables in one scope.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clear ' - delete? truncate? or even drop? You could use dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL block but that isn't 'using SQL', and is probably overkill unless tables are being added and removed (so you don't have a static list to work with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a loop on all such tables

```
BEGIN

    for table_names in (select table_name from dba_tables where table_name like 'DF\_D\_%' escape '\') 
    loop
        EXECUTE immediate 'truncate table ' ||  table_names.table_name;
    end loop;
END;
```

DBA_TABLES - [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4155.htm#REFRN23286)

Difference between `dba_tables`, `user_tables`, `all_tables` - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle/205746#205746)

Comment: Thank you. What is 'dba_tables'?

Comment: @KirillCh Updated answer.

Comment: Should I insert something instead of 'dba_tables'? Because in my PL/SQL Developer I couldn't execute this exact code.

Comment: @KirillCh - if you own those tables, just use `user_tables` instead. (If you were using `all_tables` or `dba_tables` - you don't seem to have permission to see the latter - then you'd probably want to filter on `owner` as well).

Comment: If use "delete from" instead of "truncate table" in the loop it is much faster. In my case from 30-50 seconds to 1 or less second.

Comment: @KirillCh - Maybe something else is causing that issue, `TRUNCATE` usually is much faster than `DELETE`. Have a look at [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6654614400346481630)

Comment: Absolutely. Normally Truncate is much faster. However in this particular loop "Truncate" is going about 30-50 seconds every time in my case. I have tried to change it on "Delete from" and the result is now approximetely 0.2-0.5 second every time. Just for sure currently tried Truncate - again 40 seconds.