# python cx_Oracle invalid identifier

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I'm trying to query oracle db.

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=some.server.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))'
con = cx_Oracle.connect('USER', 'PWD', dsn_tns)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = "C123456"')

res = cur.fetchall()
print res

cur.close()
con.close()
```

And got:

```
$ python cx_oracle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cx_oracle.py", line 9, in <module>
    cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = "C123456"')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I also tried to change query string to

```
'select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = 'C1012445''
```

And got:

```
$ python cx_oracle.py
  File "cx_oracle.py", line 9
    cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = 'C1012445'')
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestion?
Python version is 2.7

Comment: Try this `cur.execute("select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = 'C123456'")` does it work?

Comment: @Allan I tried this -  same ORA-00936: missing expression error

Comment: Let's do a bit more troubleshooting -> does `select sysdate from dual;` work? Try also without the `;` Let me know if this works

Comment: @Allan yeah,its works:

`$ python cx_oracle.py
[(datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 18, 16, 10, 32),)]`

Comment: Ok good, does `select * from admin.summary` work? Also what is the version of your Oracle DB?

Comment: @Allan it works, but I think I don't have permissions to view that table, so i got a error. DB version is 12
`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: You can create a table and then just query it (if you have the access to do so...)
What we have proved is that your connection to the DB does work and the DB does answer properly... Also note that your string values in the where clause should always be in single quotes, and the whole query in double quotes.

Comment: @Allan The problem is that i can query that string from other software like PLSQL, but cant from the python.

Comment: @Allan I change string to `"select * from admin.summary where 'NUMBER' = 'C123456'"` and got empty list, but in fact list need to be full of values:
`$ python cx_oracle.py
[]`

Comment: NUMBER should not be between quotes, as it is a column name.

Comment: Also have a quick look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle to check what are the tables you have access to. `SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables` and `SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tables` if you don't see your table `admin.summary` then you need to request permissions to your DBA. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUMBER` is a reserved word in SQL used for a data type.  By default it won't be a column name, unless someone forced it with:

```
SQL> create table t ("NUMBER" number);

Table created.
```

If they did this, then your SQL needs to also quote the column name like:

```
cur.execute("""select "NUMBER" from t where "NUMBER" = 1""")
```

Or, in your case, like:

```
cur.execute("""select * from admin.summary where "NUMBER" = 'C123456'""")
```

However, unless you always use the same value in the 'where' clause, you should use a bind variable for C123456.  See how https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindQuery.py does it.

Using bind variables helps scalability and helps stop SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> `cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = "C123456"'`

In SQL double-quotes are used for database identifier names (tables and columns), not string literals. So the Oracle compiler is looking for a column called `C123456`.

> `cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = 'C1012445'')`

Your string is bounded by single quotes, so it ends after the `=` and the Python interpreter doesn't know what to do with `C123456`.

Try escaping the quotes like this:

```
cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where NUMBER = ''C1012445'' ')
```

---

As @ChristopherJones points out, `NUMBER` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a name in Oracle. I assumed the posted code was a redaction but if somebody has been foolish enough to force through such a column name they must have done so by using double-quotes. In which case all subsequent references to the column must also be escaped by double-quotes:

```
cur.execute('select * from admin.summary where "NUMBER" = ''C1012445'' ')
```

Comment: NUMBER is a reserved word:```SQL> create table t (number CHAR);
create table t (number CHAR)
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```