# How to remove a strange table named "BIN$c+eOnMB3RbKSEfg/rsxtAQ==$0" from oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle and for practice I have created some tables (customer, drivers, payment, booking, location, area, job, job_history) in Oracle 11g and upon `select * from cat` statement I have found a strange table with other created tables named "BIN$c+eOnMB3RbKSEfg/rsxtAQ==$0".I don't know why this table is created.

I tried to remove this table through

```
drop table BIN$c+eOnMB3RbKSEfg/rsxtAQ==$0;
```

but it gives error:

> drop table BIN$c+<sub>*</sub>eOnMB3RbKSEfg/rsxtAQ==$0
>
> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

what should I do to remove it?

Comment: @Marmite_Bomber's answer is correct.  I'd suggest, though, that you not use the `cat` data dictionary table-- that's an object that exists solely for reasons of backwards compatibility and isn't enhanced as new features are added.  If you used the modern `user_tables`, `all_tables`, `dba_tables` views, objects in the recycle bin would automatically be filtered out.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle/205746#205746 for more details

Answer (score 10):

What you see is a deleted table in the [`RECYCLEBIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-82E62BDB-E886-4EF9-943C-C62D632E499B)

You may get the original name of the table with this query

```
SELECT original_name FROM RECYCLEBIN where OBJECT_NAME = 'BIN$c+eOnMB3RbKSEfg/rsxtAQ==$0';
```

Note that (with your parameter setting) if you DROP a table it is not completely removed, but *moved* in the recyclebin.

You may ommit this using  the `PURGE` option.

DROP TABLE xxx PURGE;

To remove the table from the recyclebin you must qoute the name with double quotes (as this is not a valid name) and **use the PURGE statement** (not a DROP - which would trigger `ORA-38301: can not perform DDL/DML over objects in Recycle Bin`).

```
PURGE TABLE "BIN$c+eOnMB3RbKSEfg/rsxtAQ==$0"
```

Alternatively you may use the `original_name` obtained with the query above:

```
PURGE TABLE {your_original_name};
```

To clean up the recyclebin completely use this statement (with the propper table user)

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```