# oracle - what is table name with prefix is BIN$

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I create partition for some Table in Oracle Db (12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production)

When i use this command to show partition info, I got TABLE_NAME with prefix "BIN$" (BIN$l6719qYYHz/gUwEAAH/8jQ==$0)

What is the meaning of this table? Why it appeared in my Database?
Can I remove it?

please leave any document about it

Thank you so much!

```
select TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME,PARTITION_NAME, num_rows , SUBPARTITION_COUNT from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS where TABLE_OWNER like '%TEST%' ;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56635763/4808122)

Answer (score 4):

Table names starting with `BIN$` are the tables that are dropped and are in the recycle bin.

`DROP TABLE` command logically moves the table to the recycle bin by renaming it.

You can see all the recycle bin objects using the following command:

```
SQL> SHOW RECYCLEBIN
ORIGINAL NAME    RECYCLEBIN NAME                OBJECT TYPE  DROP TIME
---------------- ------------------------------ ------------ -------------------
BU_TABLE         BIN$+9q0Ry8iT1ivyRponKIZ4g==$0 TABLE        2020-02-04:21:32:08
```

If you don't want the table to be stored in the recycle bin, i.e. You don't want to flashback the table then you can use `PURGE` option along with `DROP TABLE` command as:

```
DROP TABLE your_table PURGE;
```

Even you can set recycle bin ON/OFF at the session and system level.

```
-- Session
ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF;
ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = ON;

-- System
ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = OFF;
ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = ON;
```

If you have nothing to do with the dropped object, means you don't have any plans to flashback already dropped tables which are present in the recycle bin then you can `purge` the recycle bin objects using one of the following techniques:

```
PURGE TABLE tablename; -- it will remove the table from recycle bin
PURGE RECYCLEBIN; -- it will remove a current user's recycling bin 
PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN; -- it will remove entire recycle bin
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! @Tejash  Do you have document URL ? i want to read more about it