# How to find the table name based on a value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find the table name based on a value I pass in Oracle ? The query should check all the tables in the schema to check if the given value exists in any of the tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle

Comment: Why would you ever need to perform such a task? Are you hunting for malware? I have a hard time understanding a legitimate business need for doing what you are asking..

Comment: I tend to agree with @Mathguy. Finding the existence of a table is a simple as 'SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NAMEOFMYTABLE';  Why would you need a procedure for this, as implied by " based on a value I pass"?  Oh, and to account for possibility of MixedCaseNames (anathema in oracle) you would make the WHERE clause read WHERE UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = UPPER('MYTABLENAME');

Comment: @EdStevens - I think it's even worse than that. The OP wants to find a table that has a given value in a row/column combination in that table. Like "find a table that has a value of `'Mandelbrot'` in some row in one of the columns". I've seen this kind of request several times in the past, from various users. I still don't understand what a legitimate need might be for such a search. Not to mention searching for other data types: searching for a given date, for example - not even knowing if it may be stored as `date`, `timestamp` or even `varchar2`.

Comment: @mathguy - ah, on second reading I see that.

Comment: The expectation is to find the table name to help in data extraction. We don't know the table name that holds the value of a field. Hence, attempting to find out in reverse way based on the values the field has on the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description you basically have three different options with which you can achieve the desired result:

1. You can query the user_tables table and check all the tables, available on your schema. This table can be called from any user, so you won't require any specific privileges.

   SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%';
2. You can query the all_tables table. For this, most likely, you will need some better privileges as you would require when calling user_tables.

   SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%';
3. You can query the dba_tables table. As you would expect, for this table you will need great privileges to be able to retrieve the desired information.

   SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%';

**HINT:**
If you are not quite sure that you are looking for a table, you can use the ALL_OBJECTS table and identify the type of the object.

Comment: it seems you and I both mis-read/mis-understood the OP's question.  Take a look at @Mathguy response to my comment, then re-read (carefully) the OP's question.